# Error when calling already deployed contract: AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a `from` field

Tags: oracles, chainlink, brownie, error, goerli

I'm trying to create a contract that communicates with JIRA API through Chainlink Oracle on the Goerli Network.
The interaction should create a JIRA project, then write some of the returned JSON's data into the blockchain.

Heres my contracts:

JIRA Manager (Called Fractal Forge Manager):

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import "../game/GameData.sol";

contract FractalForgeManager is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {

    address public constant EMPTY_ADDRESS = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

    //Chainlink config
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    // Fractal Forge Data:
    GameData[] public projectList;

    /**
     * Goerli Testnet details:
     * Link Token: 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB
     * Oracle: 0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7 (Chainlink DevRel)
     * jobId: 53f9755920cd451a8fe46f5087468395
     */
    constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        setChainlinkToken(0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB);
        setChainlinkOracle(0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7);
        jobId = "53f9755920cd451a8fe46f5087468395";
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10; // 0,1 * 10**18 (Varies by network and job)
    }

    /**
     * Create a Chainlink request to retrieve API response, find the target data
     */
    function createGameProject(string memory projectName, string memory projectKey) public returns (bytes32 requestId)
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfillMultipleParameters.selector);

        // Set the URL to perform the POST request on
        request.add("post", "https://latinosystems.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/project");
        request.add("body", string.concat("{",
        "\"key\": \"",projectKey,"\",",
        "\"name\": \"",projectName,"\",",
        "\"projectTypeKey\": \"software\",",
        "\"leadAccountId\": \"557058:aed543b7-1ccc-4eea-9eb5-07fb1a44da29\",",
        "\"projectTemplateKey\": \"com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:gh-simplified-agility-scrum\"",
        "}"));

        request.add("path", "key");

        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequest(request, fee);
    }

    function fulfillMultipleParameters(bytes32 requestId, string memory key) public
    {
        GameData newGameProject = new GameData(key);
        projectList.push(newGameProject);
    }

    function getProjectList() view public returns(GameData[] memory)
    {
        return projectList;
    }

    function getGameDataByKeyName(string memory key) view public returns(GameData)
    {
        return projectList[0];
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < projectList.length; i++)
        {
            if(keccak256(bytes(projectList[i].gameJiraKey())) == keccak256(bytes(key)))
            {
                return projectList[0];
            }
        }
        revert('Not found');
    }
}
```

ProjectData (called game data)

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract GameData
{
    struct GameBounty
    {
        string jiraTaskID;
        uint256 bountyPrice;
        uint256 jiraScore;
    }

    string public gameJiraKey;
    GameBounty[] public bounties;

    constructor(string memory createdGameJiraKey) public
    {
        gameJiraKey = createdGameJiraKey;
    }

    function calculateTotalPoints() public view returns(uint256)
    {
        uint256 totalScore = 0;
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < bounties.length; i++)
        {
        }

        return totalScore;
    }
}
```

Through brownie, I tried to call FractalForgeManager's createGameProject right after deploying the contract, adnd themethod was called but it just didn't register anything on the blockchain.
To further test, I simply called the already existing contract like this:

```
self.fractalForgeManager = FractalForgeManager.at(address)
```

Then tried calling the createProject method

```
self.fractalForgeManager.createGameProject(projectName, projectKey)
```

But when I try to call createGameProject, I get the following error (my contracts are funded and I have eth on my test wallet):

```
Running 'scripts\deploy\Deploy.py::main'...
<scripts.deploy.DeployJiraConsumer.DeployJiraConsumer object at 0x000001D1FC00CC70>
  File "C:\Users\Levant\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 51, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\Levant\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 110, in run
    return_value = f_locals[method_name](*args, **kwargs)
  File ".\scripts\deploy\Deploy.py", line 17, in main
    print(deployJiraconsumer.createProject("TestProject1", "TestProject"))
  File ".\scripts\deploy\DeployJiraConsumer.py", line 25, in createProject
    self.fractalForgeManager.createGameProject(projectName, projectKey)
  File "C:\Users\Levant\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 1864, in __c
all__
    return self.transact(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Levant\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\contract.py", line 1732, in tra
nsact
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Final argument must be a dict of transaction parameters that includes a `from` field specifying the sen
der of the transaction
```

Any idea what the issue may be here?

Answer (score 1):

Solves, just added a map with "from"and "account" at the endof my method's parameters.

```
self.fractalForgeManager.createGameProject(projectName, projectKey, {"from": self.account})
```